# My program should give me more results than it does

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I cannot for the life of me, figure out why my program is not going through the variables associated with it at the beginning of the program.

At the end of the while loop (inside the for loop) it should display the prize won as the plinko disk moves "left/right" [+1 or -1] down the game board.

Every "tick" it moves right
Every "tock" it moves left

at the end I only get two results, either 500 or 0.

Im very new to this, I thought I had done everything correctly when I had associated the variables to the prize amounts.

```
    import random
randomNumber = random.randint( 1, 5 )
    firstMessage = "Congratulations you have " + str(randomNumber) + " disks to play with."
print (firstMessage)


plinkoNeg5 = "0"
plinkoNeg4 = "100"
plinkoNeg3 = "500"
plinkoNeg2 = "1000"
plinkoNeg1 = "0"
plinko0 = "10000"
plinko1 = "0"
plinko2 = "1000"
plinko3 = "500"
plinko4 = "100"
plinko5 = "0"

message1 = "Congratulations the disk landed in "
message2 = "Aw thats too bad, Your disk landed in "






for plinkoRun in range(randomNumber):
    plinkoTrue = True
    plinkoStop = int(5)
    plinko = 0
    while plinkoTrue <= plinkoStop:
        import random
        plinkoRandom1 = random.randint(1, 100)
        if plinkoRandom1 <= 50:
                plinko = plinko + 1
                plinkoStop = plinkoStop - 1
                print ( "tock" )
        elif plinkoRandom1 >= 50:
                plinko = plinko - 1
                plinkoStop = plinkoStop - 1
                print ( "tick" )

if plinko == -5:
        print( str(message2) + (plinkoNeg5))        
elif plinko == -4:
        print( str(message1) + (plinkoNeg4))           
elif plinko == -3:
        print( str(message1) + (plinkoNeg3))          
elif plinko == -2:
        print( str(message1) + (plinkoNeg2))            
elif plinko == -1:
        print( str(message2) + (plinkoNeg1))            
elif plinko == 0:
        print( str(message1) + (plinko0))            
elif plinko == 1:
        print( str(message1) + (plinko1))         
elif plinko == 2:
        print( str(message1) + (plinko2))           
elif plinko == 3:
        print( str(message1) + (plinko3))           
elif plinko == 4:
        print( str(message1) + (plinko4))        
elif plinko == 5:
        print( str(message2) + (plinko5))
```

Comment: post the expected output.

Comment: i don't understand plinkoTrue <= plinkoStop and the way you initialized them. How much should the while last ?

Comment: i get the ticks and tocks when i run the program

Answer (score 1):

The problems comes from the fact that your program always does 5 turns of adding/subtracting 1, this means that you can never land on any of the even numbers leaving you with only the odd numbers and all of those have the values `0` and `500`.

**Also here are some tips for your code:**

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randint( 1, 5 )
firstMessage = "Congratulations you have " + str(randomNumber) + " disks to play with."
print (firstMessage)

#This section can be replaced with a dict
#plinkoAward = {'-5': 0, '-4': 100, '-3': 500, '-2': 1000, '-1': 0, '0': 10000, '1': 0, '2': 1000, '3': 500, '4': 100, '5': 0}

plinkoNeg5 = "0"
plinkoNeg4 = "100"
plinkoNeg3 = "500"
plinkoNeg2 = "1000"
plinkoNeg1 = "0"
plinko0 = "10000"
plinko1 = "0"
plinko2 = "1000"
plinko3 = "500"
plinko4 = "100"
plinko5 = "0"

#It's better to name those strings something more meaningful for example messageWon and messageLost
message1 = "Congratulations the disk landed in "
message2 = "Aw thats too bad, Your disk landed in "


for plinkoRun in range(randomNumber):
    plinkoTrue = True

    #Change this to random.randint(0,5) if you need random number of turns
    plinkoStop = int(5)
    plinko = 0

    # The loop is not very intuitive you are comparing boolean to a number
    while plinkoTrue <= plinkoStop:

        #No need to import second time + it's generally better to add all the imports in the begging
        import random

        #You can simplify this by generating random number between 1 and 0 1 for left and 0 for right or even use something like random.getrandbits(1)
        plinkoRandom1 = random.randint(1, 100)
        if plinkoRandom1 <= 50:
                plinko = plinko + 1
                plinkoStop = plinkoStop - 1
                print ( "tock" )
        elif plinkoRandom1 >= 50:
                plinko = plinko - 1
                plinkoStop = plinkoStop - 1
                print ( "tick" )
    #This needs to be indented like this so it can execute once for every disk and not only for the last disk

    #You can dramatically simplify this by using the dictionary that I suggested at the top

    if plinko == -5:
            print( str(message2) + (plinkoNeg5))        
    elif plinko == -4:
            print( str(message1) + (plinkoNeg4))           
    elif plinko == -3:
            print( str(message1) + (plinkoNeg3))          
    elif plinko == -2:
            print( str(message1) + (plinkoNeg2))            
    elif plinko == -1:
            print( str(message2) + (plinkoNeg1))            
    elif plinko == 0:
            print( str(message1) + (plinko0))            
    elif plinko == 1:
            print( str(message1) + (plinko1))         
    elif plinko == 2:
            print( str(message1) + (plinko2))           
    elif plinko == 3:
            print( str(message1) + (plinko3))           
    elif plinko == 4:
            print( str(message1) + (plinko4))        
    elif plinko == 5:
            print( str(message2) + (plinko5))
```

**Code with suggested edits:**

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randint(1, 5)
firstMessage = "Congratulations you have " + str(randomNumber) + " disks to play with."
print(firstMessage)

plinkoAward = {"-5": "0", "-4": "100", "-3": "500", "-2": "1000", "-1": "0", "0": "10000", "1": "0", "2": "1000", "3": "500", "4": "100", "5": "0"}

messageWon = "Congratulations the disk landed in "
messageLost = "Aw that's too bad, Your disk landed in "

for plinkoRun in range(randomNumber):

    #Change this to random.randint(0,5) if you need random number of turns
    plinkoStop = int(5)
    plinko = 0

    while plinkoStop > 0:

        if random.getrandbits(1):
            plinko = plinko + 1
            plinkoStop = plinkoStop - 1
            print("tock")
        else:
            plinko = plinko - 1
            plinkoStop = plinkoStop - 1
            print("tick")

    plinko = str(plinko)

    if plinkoAward[plinko] == "0":
        print(str(messageLost) + (plinkoAward[plinko]))
    else:
        print(str(messageWon) + (plinkoAward[plinko]))
```